# Change the trailingIcon size of a TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

TextField trainlingIcon has a default size inside the class it wraps the composable inside a box with a default size

TextField.kt

```
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.layoutId(TrailingId).then(IconDefaultSizeModifier),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Decoration(
                        contentColor = trailingColor,
                        content = trailing
                    )
                }
            }
```

where the default value is defined in TextFieldImple.Kt

```
internal val IconDefaultSizeModifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(48.dp, 48.dp)
```

this causes unwanted space for the textField
is there a way to override this?

Comment: It is used to grant a minimum touch area for the icon also for accessibility reason.